# how to request distinct unique members in different olap dimension levels

Tags: mdx, olap

I am a newbie with MDX,  and it's a long time i am trying to solve a problem with my dimension, perhaps someone can help me to better understand it and, why not, find a solution.

#### The context

Here is the definition of a part of my organization (i simplify it)

```
<Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" highCardinality="false" name="Organization" caption="organization hierarchy" description="organization hierarchy of the user">
  <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="organizationid">
    <Table name="organization">
    </Table>
    <Level name="Company" visible="true" column="institution" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName">
    </Level>
    <Level name="Division" visible="true" column="site" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName">
    </Level>
    <Level name="Department" visible="true" column="department" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName">
    </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

Each user is linked to an organization, for instance look on this table

```
    organizationid, company, division, department
    1, Fruit&Co, Juice, Production
    2, Fruit&Co, Juice, Marketing
    3, Fruit&Co, Cake, Production
    4, Fruit&Co, Cake, Marketing
    5, ChocoLtd, Drinks, Production
```

Each institution has its own organization, with more levels than the 3 in the sample.

#### The problem

I want to request different things, sometimes with an aggregation on a specific level, so I dynamically create my MDX requests with the DESCENDANTS function.

For instance

```
    SELECT
      [Time].[2013] ON COLUMNS,
      DESCENDANTS(organization.[Fruit&Co],[department]) ON ROWS
    FROM [Working]
    WHERE (Measures.[Nb days])
```

Here start my problem, the result show me 4 rows instead of 2

```
    Production, 120   // in fact the sum of nb days for Juice & Cake divisions
    Marketing, 30   // sum for the 2 divisions
    Production, 120   // again, the same first row ???
    Marketing, 30   // the same second row
```

If i change unique Members = "true" into uniqueMembers="false" i have

```
    Production, 100 // Juice results
    Marketing, 25
    Production, 20 // cake results
    Marketing, 5
```

**How to have only the aggregation for the company i select, with a grouping of same level names, independantly her parents ?**

```
    Production, 120
    Marketing, 30
```

Remarks : i am using pentaho mondrian.
I tried to use DISTINC(DESCENDANTS(...)) but there is no change (i think it is due to the fact i have different organizationid for each level member).

Can someone help me ??
Thanks a lot !

Comment: sorry, of course in the dimension definition read "company" instead of "institution" and "division" instead of "site" `<Level name="Company" visible="true" column="company" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName">
    </Level>
    <Level name="Division" visible="true" column="division" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName">
    </Level>
    <Level name="Department" visible="true" column="department" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName">
    </Level>`